# Discord js - Get member's presence game

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, user-presence

how can i get the game a member is playing.
with user.presence, there is nothing in activity, even if member is playing (display on discord)
An idea ?
Console.log(user.presence)

[image]

Here is the code

```
const membre = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
console.log(membre.user.presence);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, you had to tick boxes in the portal of discord developpers, it's all new!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but it does say guild = null so maybe that is a factor?
Also, could you provide the code. EDIT: Also some games don't show up on Discord

Sorry if this is a bad answer, my first time using Stack Overflow.
Thanks :)

Comment: woops i should have commented, nvm

Comment: If I tag a bot (on which i set activity), the response is not null
but with a member who playing a game, it's null (the Game class doesn't exist anymore)
sorry for my bad english

Comment: just use, message.mentions.members.first() foryour member var, that should work

Comment: like this:
const membre = message.mentions.members.first();
console.log(membre.user.presence);

Comment: yeah i've 12.4.0